# MacBook Pro has kernel panic same time every time

Tags: kernel-panic

I purchased a second hand MacBook Pro 2015 and installed High Sierra on it and upgraded the SSD. Every day between 5-6pm it has a kernel panic and restarts. Any idea what might be behind this? I can't identify an activity trigger and its been happening daily for about 6 months.

Comment: Have you done an SMC, NVRAM/PRAM reset? Does it happen in safe-mode? Does it happen when you login to a different account? You could set up a rule to shut down automatically by night and boot back up in the morning - not a fix but could help for now. Also without any logs its basically impossible to tell what the problem may be

Comment: We need to look at the panic logs to start diagnosing this. Please use www.PasteBin.com to upload a few panic logs from `/Library/Logs/DiagnosticReports` (they will have the file extension `.panic`) and add the links to your question.

Comment: Thanks. Here is today's panic log: https://pastebin.com/vd9Q8TaD

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This panic signature reminds me of a panic I saw a while back that was caused by Norton AntiVirus, which you have installed. In fact, **[here is someone on the Norton forum](https://community.norton.com/en/comment/8388621#comment-8388621)** seeing the same thing. It's possible that you have a daily scan in the 5-6pm timeframe which hits this bug.

1. If you’re not already running the latest version of Norton AntiVirus, update to the latest.
2. If you are on the latest version and this panic continues to happen, uninstall Norton AntiVirus. Specifically, this means making sure that its four kernel extensions are uninstalled. You can verify via `kextstat | grep com.symantec`.
3. If the panic continues after uninstalling Norton, uninstall your other KEXTs (Black Magic, Soundflower, SoundGrabber).
4. If panics continue, we can start to debug them by adding symbolication to your panic output: Disable SIP, run `sudo nvram boot-args="kextsyms=1"`, reboot, and collect & upload a new panic report.

Comment: Thanks for that. The first thing I looked at after viewing the logs was to ensure the antivirus was not scheduling scans at that time. Its Symantec Enpoint Protection but I'm unsure that product is still available. I'll turn it off today and monitor. At least this gives me something to keep an eye on. Those KEXTs could probably go as well.

Comment: @Rusty How is this going?

Comment: I got a bit sidetracked by a large project - I checked for system cron jobs and scheduled Norton scans around the reboot time, but none. I uninstalled Norton and for the last few days no reboots. Fingers crossed Norton was the issue.

Comment: @Rusty is this still an issue? If this answer resolved it, can you please mark it as accepted? Thanks!

Comment: Removing Norton fixed and resolved the issue

Comment: I can't see a checkmark or any other option to resolve the post

Comment: @Rusty It should be right underneath the vote up/down arrows at the top left of my answer

Comment: There was a tick at the first answer so I checked that. Thanks